# SQL SERVER - select sum of column value multiplied by the count of other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select the sum of a column value multiplied by the count of another column

```
select
    sum(CS.revenue * count(C.subid)) as [total_revenue]
from campaigns_history CH
LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_sends CS ON CS.campaign_historyID = CH.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c C ON C.subid = cast(CS.id as nchar(255))
WHERE CH.id=19
```

I got this error:
`Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

How can I do this?

Thanks and happy programming! :)

Comment: Basically the reason you're getting this is because you are trying to multiply an aggergate (COUNT) by a non-aggregate and because the amount of rows is not the same, SQL-SRV doesn't like this. I would go with the solution below (by Eli), as this is best practice

Comment: Thanks @MikeMirabelli

Comment: @MikeMirabelli, @Eli -- please check my own answer, I didnt make myself clear when explaining the problem. `sum(c.a) * count(a.f)` isnt the same as `sum(c.a * count(a.f))` -- the first one is multiply the sum `c.a` by the count of `a.f` the second one is the sum of `c.a` value multiplied by the count of `a.f`.. Does this makes sense? Sorry my rusty english.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the `SUM` and the `COUNT` - as such:

```
select
    SUM(CS.revenue) * COUNT(C.subid) AS [total_revenue]
FROM campaigns_history CH
LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_sends CS ON CS.campaign_historyID = CH.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c C ON C.subid = CAST(CS.id as NCHAR(255))
WHERE CH.id=19
```

Answer (score 0):

You're title already gives you the answer :) Calculate the sum and multiply it by count.

```
SELECT Sum(CS.revenue) * Count(C.subid) as [total_revenue]
FROM campaigns_history CH
  LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_sends CS ON CS.campaign_historyID = CH.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN c C ON C.subid = cast(CS.id as nchar(255))
WHERE CH.id = 19
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select
    sum(
        CS.revenue * 
        (select 
             count(c.subid) 
         from c 
         where c.subid = cast(CS.id as nchar(255))
        ) as [total_revenue]
from campaigns_history CH
LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_sends CS ON CS.campaign_historyID = CH.id
WHERE CH.id=19
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, your answers didint suit my needs.
Its mostly my fault because i didnt make myself clear...

What I really need it's the sum of `CS.revenue` value multiplied by the count of `C.subid`.. Does this makes sense? Sorry my rusty english.

In order words first multiply `CS.revenue` by the count of `C.subid` and only then sum that result.

I came up with query wich returns what I expect.

```
SELECT
sum(css.total_revenue)
from (SELECT top 1 * from campaign_sends) as CS
INNER JOIN (
    select
    CS.revenue * count(C.subid) as [total_revenue]
    from campaigns_history CH
    LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_sends CS ON CS.campaign_historyID = CH.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN c C ON C.subid = cast(CS.id as nchar(255))
    WHERE
    CH.id=19
    GROUp BY CS.revenue
) as css ON css.total_revenue is not null
```